# Ensure partial is only included once per page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I ensure a Partial is only included *once* per page? I have no control of what will include it, so I need to find some kind of `ThreadLocal` context to set a `FooBarTemplateLoaded` flag that can be checked by the Partial à la

```
@if( ! MyThreadLocalContext.FooBarTemplateLoaded ) {
   @mainContent();
   MyThreadLocalContext.FooBarTemplateLoaded = true;
}
```

If anyone should wonder *why* I would like to have it only included once, it is a `<template>` block that will be injected into the required containers by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Items` to store any information with a lifespan of the current request. (ASP.NET is using `HttpContext.Current.Items` heavily behind the scenes for storing information per request)

**Runnable example code**

```
var items = HttpContext.Current.Items;
var key = "YoutubeVideoModalTemplateLoaded";
if (!(items.Contains(key)) || !(bool) items[key])
{
    @content()
    items.Add(key, true);
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Updating your answer with some runnable code.